# Laravel 5.5 Model not found in Seed class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have been around this problem for so long and cannot solve it... I found several people with (apparently) the same problem as me, but any of the answers helped me.

I have the following "Sector.php" inside "app" folder:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Sector extends Model
{
    protected $table    = 'sectors';
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    protected $guarded  = ['id'];

    public function services()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service', 'services_sectors', 'sector_id', 'service_id');
    }

    public function observations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Observation', 'observations_sectors', 'sector_id', 'observation_id');
    }
}
```

And the following "DatabaseSeeder.php" inside "database/seeds":

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;


class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('sectors')->delete();

        Sector::create(['name' => 'Health']);

        $this->command->info('Sectors table seeded');
    }
}
```

So, when I access my server I run the command `php artisan db:seed` but I have the following error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Class 'Sector' not found
```

I have been trying `./composer update`, `./composer dump-autoload -o`, changing `Sector` to `App\Sector` in the seeder file but the error just changes to `Class 'App\Sector' not found`.

If I add `use App\Sector;` to the top of the Seeder file the error is the same.

It seems I tried all the solutions that are online, so maybe I have some configuration done incorrectly? Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `use App\Sector;` to your seeding file.

Once you have it working, think about separating your seeding files into their separate classes.  It is much easier to maintain that way.

**Generate Seeder File**

First, in terminal, generate a new seed file:

```
php artisan make:seeder SectorsTableSeeder
```

Transfer your seeding code into the `run` method of this new file.

**Call seeder files**

Then, modify the `DatabaseSeeder.php` file to run the `SectorsTableSeeder` class.  For example:

```
public function run()
    {
        $this->call(SectorsTableSeeder::class);

    }
```

**Update**

Sorry, I missed that part.

This is what I would try:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

public function run()
    {
        DB::table('sectors')->delete();

        DB::table('sectors')->insert([
            'name' => 'Health',
            'created_at' => $now,
            'updated_at' => $now,
        ]);

        $this->command->info('Sectors table seeded');
    }
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work as well. The error is the same: `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Class 'App\Sector' not found`

Comment: For your update: I just used `DB::table('sectors')->insert(['name' => 'Health']);` and indeed it worked. But why? It seems I'm loosing Eloquent like this, no?

Comment: I was trying to follow this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/migrations#database-seeding

Comment: The general preference is to use DB inserts as they are faster (concurrent inserts, no need to load model, etc).  However, you can use model factories.  I tend to only think of these when using the `faker` library, but that would  work in this instance too.  I'll add an example.

Comment: Ok, I've looked more carefully to the documentation and it seems that for Laravel 5.5 they are using a lot the `DB::table()`, while that was not the case in 5.0. Was this something that changed? I'm just wondering because maybe the fact of not being able to use Eloquent means that I have some configuration wrong. Because it seems that theoretically I should be able to do what I wanted to do in my question?

Comment: No, using factory models would be very cumbersome to seed more than one row, so I would stick to DB inserts as shown in your link from the Laravel docs.  I don't think this has changed since 5.0.  I've never really thought of why Eloquent models aren't supported.  I guess that seeding is more about inserting data and not about interacting with models.

Comment: Ok, I will then accept your answer. If I have problems later using Eloquent in other places I can always write another question. Thank you very much for the help